# Enabling Bigtable Emulator through GithubActions

Tags: go, bigtable

I am trying to run integration tests for my system.

For running the tests I am using GitHub actions CI/CD which runs tests on PRs

I have tried adding it to my test runner

```
- name: install and run gcloud
        run: |
          curl -s https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-410.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz --output /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
          cd /tmp && tar xzf google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
          ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --quiet
          ./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud --quiet beta emulators bigtable start  --project=google_cloud_tests &
      - name: Set Git credentials
        env:
          TOKEN: ${{ secrets.gh-bot-token }}
        run: |
          make gh-actions-git-creds
      - name: Start services
        env:
          PGHOST: localhost
          PGUSER: postgres
          PGPASSWORD: development
        run: |
          make docker-init
      - name: Update DB seeds
        run: |
          make update-db-seeds
      - name: Install testmo cli
        run: make install-testmo
      - name: Add github configs to testmo
        run: make testmo-send-config
      - name: Run tests
        run: make ${{ inputs.task }}
        env:
          GOTESTSUM_JUNITFILE: tests_results.xml
          GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID: google_cloud_tests
          GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID: google_cloud_tests
          INSTANCE_ID: google_cloud_tests
          BIGTABLE_EMULATOR_HOST: localhost:8086
```

But I am still getting this issue

```
{"l":"error","a":"tests","t":"2023-07-07T16:47:51Z","m":"Got a APIError on 'PUT /api/user/2450001108/notes' create bigtable client: failed to initialize client: dialing: google: could not find default credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information. "}
```

So, in the test environment I am not sure if we should set these variables or whether it should be automatically set by the emulator.

How should I go about solving this?

I added the configuration to tests.yaml which I provided above. Tried exporting some variables as a step as well. But doesn't seem to work.
I am trying to use the GoLang Bigtable client.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide more information about your project structure, including the code where the GoLang Bigtable client is initialized, as well as any additional relevant details that could help us further diagnose the problem?

In the meantime, you can try following these steps to resolve the issue:

1. Generate a service account key from the Google Cloud Console
2. In your GitHub Actions workflow, set the environment variables required for authentication. Set an environment variable to the path of the service account key file.

```
name: Set Google Cloud credentials
run: |
  echo "${{ secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS }}" > $HOME/gcloud.json
  echo "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$HOME/gcloud.json" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

3. Use the environment variables in the test. Export the environment variable for the test session, ensuring that the GoLang Bigtable client can find the credentials specified in `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.